# How to declare global variables for simulink containing matlab functions?

Tags: matlab, global, simulink

I'm building a Simulink model with multiple Matlab [function blocks](http://in.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunction.html). Each of these function blocks has a lot of constants, for example, `g = 9.8`, common between them. I want to initialize all of these constants in one go so that I don't have to do so in each function block.

I tried initializing all the variables in Matlab workspace, but they don't seem to be working.

What is the best and easiest way to go forward with this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to either define your global variables as `Simulink.Signal` object or a [Data Store Memory](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/datastorememory.html) block and then define them as global in your MATLAB function. You cannot access the regular MATLAB variables from MATLAB workspace.

There is a [detailed page](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-global-data-with-the-matlab-function-block.html) about this on MAthworks website with [a good example](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-global-data-with-the-matlab-function-block.html#bsdud7d-3).

Comment: For each data I want to store I have to use one block of data store memory? I have atleast 50 constants which I want as global variables.

Answer (score 0):

The canonical method for adding variables/constants across your Simulink model is to use the Model Explorer from the MODELING tab or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>:

[image]

select either the Base Workspace or the ModelWorkspace

[image]

from the Meubar select Add and then select the MATLAB Variable or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

[image]

change the variable name by double-clicking it in the table and its value on the right panel:

[image]