# Simulink: How to use a global array in a Matlab function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I'm trying to create a moving average window for temperature sensor data.

I've followed:
[How to declare global variables for simulink containing matlab functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451729/how-to-declare-global-variables-for-simulink-containing-matlab-functions) and https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-global-data-with-the-matlab-function-block.html

which explain how to do this for a single variable ie (A=5 and I can play around with A)

How do I do this with a global array/vector that I can edit the values of?

Simply doing

```
function y = fcn(u)
global A
A = [];

A(end+1)=u;

y = sum(A)/length(A)+10;
```

does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are reinitializing your global `A` variable each time you call the function. Do this instead:

```
function y = fcn(u)
global A

A(end+1)=u;
y = sum(A)/length(A)+10;
```

(Of course, if you are using this as part of a Simulink operation, you will need to add logic to keep the array from growing too far. I assume you generated a minimal example for purposes of the question.)

---

In many cases, an improvement is to use a `persistent` instead of a `global`. Persistent variables are kept between multiple call to a function, but are not available to any other function. This prevents unexpected changes to your variables. (Especially if your operational code uses a variable named "A".)

```
function y = fcn(u)
persistent A

A(end+1)=u;
y = sum(A)/length(A)+10;
```

---

A more general approach for using `global` or `persistent` variables is to is an `isempty` check to see if it needs to be initialized. Like this:

```
function y = fcn(u)
persistent A

if isempty(A)
    A = 0;  %Or whatever the appropriate initial value is. An empty array is the default.
end

A(end+1)=u;
y = sum(A)/length(A)+10;
```